# Mercurial - Merge with non-head revision

Tags: mercurial, branch, bookmarks

I was working on a project and when I was ready for a `0.1.0` release I created a bookmark called `release`, tagged that revision as `0.1.0`, and then made the bookmark inactive and continued working on my project.

The revisions look something like this (from newest to oldest):

- `Tip` (`hg update default` goes here)
- *Some more revisions*
- Revision with bookmark (`hg update release` goes here)
- *Some more revisions*

My intention was to do `hg update release` followed by `hg merge default` and `hg tag <version>` whenever a new version was ready. However, that produces the following error:

> abort: nothing to merge (use 'hg update' or check 'hg heads')

I obviously only have one head and I'm not sure what `hg update` would do. `hg update release` when I am at the tip *does* update to the proper revision. Is there a way, given my current scenario and still using bookmarks (no named branched), to merge the revision pointed to by `release` with the tip (thereby creating a new head)? My initial thought is to make a small change to `release`, commit it in order to create a new head, and then merge; however, I would rather be sure of what I am doing before I try that.

Comment: Could you show a partial revision graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging is only needed when you have multiple heads, i.e., non-linear history.

However, I'm not really sure if your workflow is more complicated than it should.  Keep in mind that you are **not** forced to update to a particular revision in order to tag it.  See the [help for the `tag` command](http://selenic.com/hg/help/tag).

Comment: The basic idea is that I want to maintain a release branch using bookmarks instead of named branches.

Comment: @KPthunder: Either if you use named branches or not, a release _branch_ implies branching.  A release policy over linear history is just tagging.